# Difference between stock[item] -= 1 and stock[item] = stock[item] - 1?

Tags: python

I've trying to write a small program that computes a bill based on certain lists. One of the requirements is to change to stock depending on what is taken out. I wrote my code the following way, and at least conceptually speaking, feel like I have the right idea.

```
shopping_list = ["banana", "orange", "apple"]

stock = {
"banana": 6,
"apple": 0,
"orange": 32,
"pear": 15
}

prices = {
"banana": 4,
"apple": 2,
"orange": 1.5,
"pear": 3
}

def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0
    for item in food:
        if stock[item] > 0:
            total += prices[item]
            stock[item] = stock[item] - 1
            return total
        else:
            return "Sorry: Out of Stock"
    return total
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. I've looked up a potential solution and found one that goes like this.

```
groceries = ["banana", "orange","apple"]

stock = {"banana": 6,
"apple": 0,
"orange": 32,
"pear": 15
}

prices = {"banana": 4,
"apple": 2,
"orange": 1.5,
"pear": 3
}

def computeBill(food):
    total = 0
    for item in food:  
        if stock[item] > 0: 
            total += prices[item] 
            stock[item] -= 1
    return total

print computeBill(groceries)
```

The main difference I see lies in these pieces of code:

```
stock[item] = stock[item] - 1

stock[item] -= 1
```

What is the main difference between the two and why does the second one work? And what exactly does "-=" do? I could understand if it was a different method of getting the same thing to work, but that they're not equivalent leaves me confounded. Any input would be greatly appreciated and apologies in advance for my ignorance/stupidity.

Comment: Those should be the same. `-=` just subtracts in place.

Comment: Please fix your indentation. There's no way to know what's wrong with your code when we can only guess what the correct version of it is.

Comment: Also, when you call return, the function the return is in exits. So, in the first example above, compute_bill will stop after examining the first item, apple. This was fixed in the second function, and might be why the first wasn't working as you expected.

Comment: The reason why your code doesn't work is because you have too many `return` statements in weird places.

Comment: While `x -= y` and `x = x - y` are slightly different with some data types, that's not the problem you're running into.

Answer (score 1):

With numerical variables, the operator `-=` is exactly the same as assigning one less than the current value. But there's another difference between the two versions: Your solution returns a value as soon as you examine one element in your shopping list. Returning terminates the function, so only do it when you're done calculating.

Comment: Thank you for that. So in this case, would the solution be a print function as opposed to a return function in events where there is no stock?

Comment: What you do in out of stock cases is up to you; just make sure that you can continue going through the shopping list (so no `return`), and that you calculate a valid total (don't add a charge for what isn't there to buy).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely this:

```
for item in food:
    if stock[item] > 0:
        total += prices[item]
        stock[item] = stock[item] - 1
        return total
```

Here, you're returning in the middle of the loop, so it will only ever process one item from `food`.  In the second example, the only return statement is at the end of the loop.

Comment: Much appreciated my friend. So in this case, would I just print both statements instead of returning them in order to let the loop continue? The only reason I had the return functions was because I thought I needed to include them in order to demarcate specific premises: i.e. in this case return this, if we're out of stock return this.

Comment: It depends, `prints` are good for debugging, but don't have much of a purpose in a production application.  What should happen if you're out of stock?  The calling function should be aware that the total they receive back doesn't include some items.  Generally, situations like this are handled by raising `Exceptions`.  This allows the calling function to possibly catch the exception and decide what to do, like tell the user that a product is out of stock and prevent them from checking out.

Answer (score 0):

What better way to show you the difference but by running a program that demonstrates the difference? Try running the following program and noting what it prints to your screen.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
def main():
    stock = dict(apple=Number(100))
    item = 'apple'
    print('Memory location of stock[item]:', id(stock[item]))
    stock[item] -= 1
    print('Memory location of stock[item]:', id(stock[item]))
    stock[item] = stock[item] - 1
    print('Memory location of stock[item]:', id(stock[item]))


class Number:

    __slots__ = '__value'

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.__value = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.__value)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        type_of_self = type(self)
        if isinstance(other, type_of_self):
            other = other.__value
        return type_of_self(self.__value - other)

    def __isub__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, type(self)):
            other = other.__value
        self.__value -= other
        return self


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The first operation may alter the object in place. The second operation will create a new object and replace the old one. Please note that is answers your question but not solve your problem.

Comment: You're only showing that it's _possible_ for the two operators to have different effects. While you are right about this, there is no difference when the operators are applied to numerical variables.

Comment: ... and the reason for this is because objects of type `int` are immutable. That is precisely why I said *may* when talking about alterations.

Comment: No, it's not just immutability. But you can more easily demonstrate the difference with lists, which are mutable. Anyway none of this is going to help the OP.

Comment: ... and that was admitted in the answer. However, it may help another person having a similar question in the future. My answer is targeted at the title, not the problem.